# Issue regarding showing Hierarchical data sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

my data is coming like this way which is not my required output.

```
JID         EntryDate    RefundDate      Comments      Refund   ActionBy     nLevel
------      ------------ --------------  ----------    ------   --------     ------
41986       NULL          NULL            NULL         NULL     NULL         1
41985       NULL          NULL            NULL         NULL     NULL         1
NULL        2013-12-17    2013-12-24      Cancel       0        tridip       2
NULL        2013-12-17    2013-12-25      done         1        tridip       2
NULL        2013-12-17    2013-12-24      no           0        tridip       2
NULL        2013-12-18    2013-12-25      testing      0        tridip       2
NULL        2013-12-18    2013-12-25      done now     1        tridip       2
```

but i want to have the output like below way like parent child relationship

```
JID         EntryDate    RefundDate      Comments      Refund   ActionBy     nLevel
------      ------------ --------------  ----------    ------   --------     ------
41986       NULL          NULL            NULL         NULL     NULL         1
NULL        2013-12-17    2013-12-24      no           0        tridip       2
NULL        2013-12-17    2013-12-25      testing      0        tridip       2
NULL        2013-12-17    2013-12-25      done now     1        tridip       2

41985       NULL          NULL            NULL         NULL     NULL         1
NULL        2013-12-18    2013-12-24      Cancel       0        tridip       2
NULL        2013-12-18    2013-12-25      done         1        tridip       2
```

i try to build the parent child relation ship by CID but still the output is not coming the way i want. so here is my sql which i am issuing to have the output.

```
;WITH  Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT  JID
            ,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) EntryDate
            ,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) RefundDate
            ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) Comments
            ,CAST(NULL AS BIT) Refund
            ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(30)) ActionBy
            ,nLevel = 1
            ,CAST(NULL AS INT) AS CID
    FROM refundrequested
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   CAST(NULL AS INT) JID
            ,E.EntryDate
            ,E.RefundDate
            ,E.Comments
            ,E.Refund
            ,E.ActionBy
            ,H.nLevel+1
            ,H.JID  AS CID

    FROM refundrequested   E
    JOIN Hierarchy  H ON E.JID = H.JID

)

SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY JID DESC, nLevel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the way you sort. NULLs come last with DESC sort.

You can solve it by adding CID to first sorting column when JID is NULL:

```
;WITH  Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT  JID
            ,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) EntryDate
            ,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) RefundDate
            ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) Comments
            ,CAST(NULL AS BIT) Refund
            ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(30)) ActionBy
            ,nLevel = 1
            ,CAST(NULL AS INT) AS CID
    FROM refundrequested
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   CAST(NULL AS INT) JID
            ,E.EntryDate
            ,E.RefundDate
            ,E.Comments
            ,E.Refund
            ,E.ActionBy
            ,H.nLevel+1
            ,H.JID  AS CID

    FROM refundrequested   E
    JOIN Hierarchy  H ON E.JID = H.JID

)

SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY COALESCE(JID, CID) DESC, nLevel
```